# How do I change the css of a different element on hover?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I am creating a thermometer graphic that looks like this:

[image]

and highlights a section of the thermometer on hover. The problem is that the first segment is created from two overlapping divs. This means that when I hover over the first segment, this happens:

[image]

How can I edit my css to highlight the first segment AND the circle at the start of the thermometer whenever the user hovers over either? I would prefer a css-based solution, but if that isn't possible, I am happy to use javascript/jquery instead. Current HTML and CSS below.

```
<div class="thermo">
    <div class="startthermo">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="thermopadding">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="thermalcapsule" style="width: 10%">
        <div class="thermal thermal1">1</div>
        100
    </div>
    <div class="thermalcapsule" style="width: 15%">
        <div class="thermal thermal2">2</div>
        200
    </div>
    <!-- More HTML here -->
</div>

.thermo {
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.thermalcapsule {
    margin-right: 1px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.thermalcapsule:hover .thermal1{
    background-color: #000000;
}

.thermoimage {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    float: left;
}

.thermopadding {
    width: 2%;
    float:left;
}

.startthermo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #60A4CE;
    border: 9px solid #f4f4f4;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
}

.thermal {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    z-index : 5;
}

.thermal1 {
    background-color: #60A4CE;
}

.thermal2 {
    background-color: #437C87;
}
```

Comment: you have z-index problem, but i think you need rethink you're html tag for work perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/y9XEC/

Comment: with z-index => http://jsfiddle.net/y9XEC/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem like this, i hope it helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/bVDVm/

```
<div class="thermo">
    <div class="thermopadding">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="thermalcapsule" style="width: 15%">
        <div class="startthermo">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="thermal thermal1">1</div>
        100
    </div>
    <div class="thermalcapsule" style="width: 15%">
        <div class="thermal thermal2">2</div>
        200
    </div>
    <!-- More HTML here -->
</div>

.thermalcapsule:hover .startthermo,
.thermalcapsule:hover .thermal1{
    background-color: #000000;
}

.startthermo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #60A4CE;
    border: 9px solid #f4f4f4;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -35px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: nice idea for add :hover on startthermo

Comment: nice solution and with this markup, you can simplify it even more:


.thermalcapsule:hover div{
    background-color: #000000;
}

Comment: Thanks Matus. I used your simplification as it gives me the added bonus of highlighting each capsule on hover with one statement.

Answer (score 1):

First change the HTML part to:

```
<div class="thermo">
  <div class="thermalcapsule" style="width: 20%">
    <div class="thermal thermal1">1</div>
    100
  </div>
  <div class="thermalcapsule" style="width: 15%">
    <div class="thermal thermal2">2</div>
    200
  </div>
  <!-- More HTML here -->

  <div class="startthermo">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Then, use this selector to change `background-color` of the circle:

```
.thermalcapsule:first-of-type:hover ~ .startthermo {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

**What is the benefit?**

In this case, If `.thermalcapsule` elements are rendered dynamically, you don't have to check whether the current capsule is the first one or not.

In this example I removed the `.thermopadding` element and used following style to apply the effect:

```
.thermalcapsule:first-of-type {
  /* instead of using .thermopadding */
  margin-left: 2%;
}
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/idekis/1/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

```
.thermalcapsule:hover .thermal1 {
  background-color: #000000; //remove this line
  background-color: #60A4CE; add below one
}
```

Comment: i think he wants other color on :hover

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the pure css answer, but here's how you can do it with JavaScript:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drvic10k/v3US8/)

You create a wrapper element around those 2 elements, that you want to highlight together and use its mouseenter and mouseleave events to change class of the inner elements.

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {

            $(".wrapper").mouseenter(function () {

                var $this = $(this);
                $("div", $this).addClass("highlighted");

            });

            $(".wrapper").mouseleave(function () {

                var $this = $(this);
                $("div", $this).removeClass("highlighted");

            });

});
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div2"></div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1 {
    background-color:red;
    min-height:50px;
    min-width:100px;
}

.div2 {
    background-color:blue;
    min-height:50px;
    min-width:100px;
}

.highlighted {

    background-color:green;

}
```